# NodeJS Undefined JSON Value

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm trying to get `app_data` because this holds other data that I need, such as quality, but every time I try to log app_data it comes up with undefined, logging itemJson works fine?

**Code**

```
function getBPPrice(item, itemJson){
     console.log(itemJson);
     console.log(itemJson.app_data);
     console.log(itemJson.app_data.quality);
     console.log(Prices.response.items[item].prices[itemJson.app_data.quality][itemJson.tradable].Craftable[0].value);
}
```

and

```
var item = theirItems[i].market_name;
var itemJson = JSON.stringify(theirItems[i], null, 4);

getBPPrice(item, itemJson);
```

Now, console.log(itemJson); works as I've stated before, but console.log(itemJson.app_data); just outputs undefined, so the next output which is the quality value doesn't work.

**Json**

https://pastebin.com/cFSd6GLU

Pastebin link because it is quite long, app_data is near the bottom too.

Edit:

Error i get -

> undefined C:\Users\datpe\Desktop\d\bot.js:89
>            console.log(itemJson.app_data.quality);
>                                         ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'quality' of undefined
>       at getBPPrice (C:\Users\datpe\Desktop\d\bot.js:89:32)
>       at processOffer (C:\Users\datpe\Desktop\d\bot.js:136:4)
>       at TradeOfferManager.manager.on (C:\Users\datpe\Desktop\d\bot.js:189:2)
>       at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
>       at TradeOfferManager.emit (events.js:210:7)
>       at received.forEach (C:\Users\datpe\node_modules\steam-tradeoffer-manager\lib\polling.js:235:10)
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at getOffers (C:\Users\datpe\node_modules\steam-tradeoffer-manager\lib\polling.js:219:12)
>       at Helpers.checkNeededDescriptions (C:\Users\datpe\node_modules\steam-tradeoffer-manager\lib\index.js:483:4)
>       at Async.map (C:\Users\datpe\node_modules\steam-tradeoffer-manager\lib\assets.js:171:4)

Comment: Second argument to [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) is a "replacer". If you are simply after "pretty printing" without modification then you want `undefined` there instead, since that's least likely to actually match anything ( since undefined is not really a JSON output thing ). But you can't access a property from a string, so you seem to have a couple of concepts wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not 100% clear what you are trying to do here, but it looks like you have an an array `theirItems` and each member of `theirItems` is an object that you want. But when you do this…

```
var itemJson = JSON.stringify(theirItems[i], null, 4);
```

`itemJson` is now a **string** representing the object you want, not the object itself. You can't then access individual elements of the object like:

```
itemJson.app_data
```

because its a string, not the actual object.

I think what you want to do is simply grab the object itself and pass that to your function:

```
var itemJson = theirItems[i]
// then pass the actual object:
getBPPrice(item, itemJson);
```